# Preview XML in VS Code

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, xslt, atom-editor

I'm an Atom user, but I'm switching to Visual Studio Code.
When editing XML in Atom I can preview how its HTML would look like according to the XSL file of the XML header (copied below). For that purpose, I use Atom Browser or Browser Plus packages, so I don't need to execute any task or generate an HTML file, just click on *Preview*.

I wonder if there's any way to do something similar in VSCode. Thanks.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='.../styles.xsl'?>
<!DOCTYPE TEI SYSTEM '.../dtd.dtd'>
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, but you may still be able to achieve what you need - with a little effort.

Visual Studio Code does not have any built-in XSLT capability (there's an [XSLT/XPath language extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xslt-xpath) but this lacks the preview feature you want). There are also no Visual Studio Code extensions that I know of that provide a general purpose 'HTML Preview' feature driven by XSLT.

You do however have the option to write your own [WebView](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview) extension to preview XML in this way for a limited (due to security constraints) set of XSLT stylesheet modules. The XSLT would be maintained within the extension.

The [CALS Table Viewer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.cals-table-viewer) (that I maintain) may be useful as a 'template project' which you could modify to fit your needs. The extension uses the [Saxon-JS](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml) XSLT 3.0 Processor.

There's quite a lot of boiler-plate code but, to start with, you would just need to substitute in your own (compiled) XSLT. Here's the JavaScript statement that returns the WebView HTML to give you an idea:

```js
            return `<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <!--
                    Use a content security policy to only allow loading images from https or from our extension directory,
                    and only allow scripts that have a specific nonce.
                -->
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; style-src ${webview.cspSource}; connect-src ${webview.cspSource}; img-src ${webview.cspSource} https:; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <link href="${stylesResetUri}" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="${stylesMainUri}" rel="stylesheet">
                <title>CALS Table Viewer</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="main"></div>
                <div id="end"></div>
                <script nonce="${nonce}">var saxonData = {'sef': ${JSON.stringify(this.sefURI)}}</script>
                <script nonce="${nonce}" src="${scriptSaxonUri}"></script>
                <script nonce="${nonce}" src="${scriptUri}"></script>
            </body>
            </html>`;
```

Comment: thank you! I'll try that. Sorry not to have answered or tried this yet, I'll do it as soon as I can

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry for the delay... I was trying to do this, but I was unable, as I'm not quite experienced with code... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @pgfearo I was able to get this working, based on your code. One newbie question: When I updated vscode.engine to current (^1.75.1 from ^1.47) the extension stopped working. Curious if you've tried updating the vscode.engine in your extension.

Comment: @tubwreck  Glad it's working (at least with the old VS Code API). I haven't tried updating the vscode.engine yet. It's possible that there's a typing conflict with the updated vscode API types in index.d.ts. If that's the case you should see problems reported in your TypeScript code.

Comment: @pgfearo I found the issue with the newer engine version. Starting with 1.60, they change how resource paths are used. The fix was to use webview.asWebViewUri to convert the paths to URIs: `const scriptUri = webview.asWebviewUri(scriptPathOnDisk); '

Comment: @tubwreck thanks, I'll update my extension too

Comment: @pgfearo I need to specify additional command line options to saxon for the compilation (specifically -relocate:on). How do I do this in the tasks.json? A related question, the command currently uses the -nogo option (as it should). Where is that specified?

Comment: @tubwreck 'relocate:on' is not yet supported but will be soon, your other question: -nogo is used with the 'execute:false' tasks.json property setting

Comment: @pgfearo is the correspondence between command line options and tasks.json property settings documented anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: @tubwreck each tasks.json property has its own description - which you see when edit tasks.json, however this doesn't mention corresponding cmd-line arg names. The best documentation for that is the code that does the mapping: https://github.com/DeltaXML/vscode-xslt-tokenizer/blob/master/src/saxonJsTaskProvider.ts

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [tei-publisher-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=e-editiones.tei-publisher-vscode) extension, which includes a preview functionality (cmd-shift-a / ctrl-shift-a), using ODD and TEI Publisher to transform into html.

Comment: Thanks! Could use my own ODD instead?

Comment: I haven't used it like that before. Not sure if you could upload and use your own ODD on [TEI Publisher](https://teipublisher.com/exist/apps/tei-publisher/index.html?tab=0) without everyone else seeing it. You could ask the maintainer of the plugin on their [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/eeditiones/tei-publisher-vscode/issues)

Comment: Doesnt work, I've tried multiple ODD's.. which one to chose that works?